# How to create shortcut to terminal command on Manjaro 21.0 Deepin?

Tags: linux, terminal, shortcuts, manjaro

I want to have easier access to the terminal command `espanso stop` (for some reason it's forgettable to me). How do I make it into a desktop shortcut? I'm running Manjaro Linux 21.0 with the Deepin desktop environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using the terminal, you can create an alias by adding the following line to `~/.bashrc` and restart the terminal session:

```
alias es='espanso stop'
```

Now, you only need to type `es`.

If you really want to have a desktop shortcut, you can create a script on desktop, let's say named `stop-espanso.sh`, with content:

```
#! /bin/sh
espanso stop
```

And you need to make the script file executable with the following command:

```
chmod +x stop-espanso.sh
```

Now you can double-click to the script file.